# How to retrieve passed data from Navigator.Pop

Tags: flutter

How can I retrieve data passed through Navigator.pop, and display it on a text widget?

This is the data I want to pass below

```
return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'This is the passed data');
                },
                child: _buildItem(context));
```

This is where I want to retrieve the passed data:

```
class PassedData extends StatelessWidget {
  PassedData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Text('How can I display the passed data here?'));
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: Yes just await the result Navigator push

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the result when navigating to this page and handle the result after poping it.

You should have something like this:

```
String result = await Navigator.push(/*screen containing the Navigator.pop with data*/);
textInUI = result ?? '';
setState(() {});
```